# gesture navigation bar transparency expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Using expo sdk v49

I am using navigation gestures and there is a white background behind it how can I make it transparent

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sldw5.jpg)

Tried many solutions and searching online but there seems to be nothing on this

Btw I tried this on emulator a Samsung device and a xiaomi device

Asking for
Option to change gesture navigation bar color

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

npx expo install expo-navigation-bar

...then put the following in your app.js

```
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";

NavigationBar.setPositionAsync("absolute");
NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync("#ffffff01");
```

...for fully transparent gesture and 3-button navigation background. Not sure there is a way to differentiate between 3-button and gesture navigation though so it will be transparent for both.